# Difference of two Bernoulli Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to know the distribution of $|X-Y|$, where each of $X,Y \sim Ber(p)$ and they are independent.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, Then $|X-Y|=1$ if and of if $(X,Y)=(1,0)$ or $(X,Y)=(0,1)$. Each of these events happens with probability $p(1-p)$. Otherwise $|X-Y|=0$.

Hence $$|X-Y| \sim Ber(2p(1-p))$$